# Python pathlib Path().mkdir() applies desired mode to final directory, but mode-umask mode to parents - bug?

Tags: python, permissions, parent, mkdir, pathlib

I am using pathlib to set up a folder structure, for which I'd like permissions set to drwxrwx--- (770) for all folders in the tree.

My current code is:

```
p=Path('name/{}/{}/{}/category'.format(year,month,day))
pp=Path('name/{}/{}/{}'.format(year,month,day))
p.mkdir(mode=0o770,parents=True,exist_ok=True)
```

I need `exist_ok=True` as I want the same line to work as I loop through `category` values. However, while testing this I'm deleting the folders.

After running,

```
oct(p.stat().st_mode)
0o40770
oct(pp.stat().st_mode)
0o40775
```

i.e., the parent directories have default permissions of 777 (with umask=002).

The only way around this I can think of, which seems inefficient, is:

```
p.mkdir(mode=0o770,parents=True,exist_ok=True)
os.system("chmod -R 770 {}".format(name))
```

Is there a way to apply the desired permissions with the `Path().mkdir()` call, or is the `os.system()` call unavoidable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.mkdir) for `Path.mkdir` mentions this behavior:

> If `parents` is true, any missing parents of this path are created as needed; they are created with the default permissions without taking mode into account (mimicking the POSIX mkdir -p command).

One way to avoid this would be to iterate over each path's `parts` or `parents` yourself, calling `mkdir` with `exists_ok` but without `parents` on each. That way, the missing directories are still created, but the `mode` is taken into account. That would look something like:

```
for parent in reversed(p.parents):
    parent.mkdir(mode=0o770, exist_ok=True)
```

Comment: Excellent! Requires an additional `p.mkdir(mode=0o770,exist_ok=True)`, but I'm happy with that.